# How to test props in React-typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, testing, react-props

I'm working on a react-typescript project and I want to test props passed to a react component using react-testing library.

here is my SharedDashboardUiLatestValueWidget.tsx component

```
export interface SharedDashboardUiLatestValueWidgetProps {
  title?: string,
  value: number,
  type: 'temperature' | 'humidity',
  varient: 'small' | 'big',
  backgroundColor?:string,
  titleColor?:string,
  valueColor:string
}

export function SharedDashboardUiLatestValueWidget(
  props: SharedDashboardUiLatestValueWidgetProps
) {

  if (props.varient === 'small') {
    return <Card  elevation={4} sx={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', boxSizing: 'border-box',backgroundColor:props.backgroundColor}} >
      <CardContent sx={{ display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column' }} >
        <Typography  variant='h5' sx={{m:1, fontSize:30,color:props.titleColor}}>
          {props.title || ""}
        </Typography>
        <Typography data-testid="type" variant='h4' sx={{m:1, color:props.valueColor}}>
          { props.value }
          { props.type === 'temperature' ? " °C" : props.type === 'humidity' ? " %" : "" }
        </Typography>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
...
```

This is my testing code

```
describe('SharedDashboardUiLatestValueWidget', () => {

  it('should render SharedDashboardUiLatestValueWidget Props correctly', ()=>{
     render(<SharedDashboardUiLatestValueWidget value={0} type={'temperature'} varient={'big'} valueColor={''} />);
     expect(screen.queryByTestId("type")).toBe('temperature');

  })

});
```

Even though I passed the values for props I received `null` value. Can someone help me to test the props in this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first things first your `variant` prop has the value `big` and your if statement in your component is only true if `variant` is small so your test not working is to be expected. Also `screen.queryByTestId` returns a node, if the data-testid is found, which is not comparable to a string, if you want to test for the contents of the element I believe you can use `.innerHTML` for that. Now that that's out of the way I can tell you how I like to write tests like these. Now keep in mind that I'm not claiming my methods to be the best just what I find to work well. If you want to test if the props work as intended you need to test if the elements in the component are affected as expected depending on the values if your props. For example if you pass props to your component where `varient` is `small`, `value` is `0`, and `type` is `temperature` you would expect `screen.queryByTestId("test").innerHTML` to be `0°C`. And then make a test where you change one of the props, and check that the component now behaves in a different way as expected.